Bokeh HoverTool not showing time stamp in correct format
Whenever I plot any graph having the time in the "hh:mm:ss" format and use hover tool for seeing the timestamp in the same format at any point in the plot, I see a decimal number having an exponential degree.
For example, the time is "23:04:12", I would see some random number having value "5.8373e7".
Kindly run the "Test.ipynb" code with the example "Dummy.csv", both given in the following google drive link, for better clarity on my question.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_FAp4ASuwBJxl6Mtp0xQwxSQ1Zcl9vvx
I would be highly obliged if anyone could give me a solution to this issue so that I can see the timestamp in the "hh:mm:ss" format on the hover tool.
Thanks in advance!

Please post your code as a minimal example and not as a link in future.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It is possible to enable predefiened formatting schemes for your Hovertool.
You can use common formates adding the column name and the type "numeral", "datetime" and "printf" to the parameter formatters as a dict.
The parameter tooltips takes a list of (name, field) pairs describing what the hover tool should display when there is a hit. Here you can make use of formatting short cuts.
For the "datetime" formatting you can check out the DatetimeTickFormatter for a list of all supported short cuts.
Also add the renderers you want to activate the HoverTool for to the renderers parameter and add the tool to your plot.
See also the minimal example below.
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import HoverTool
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

data = {
    'datetime': ['2024-04-14', '2024-04-15', '2024-04-16', '2024-04-17', '2024-04-18', '2024-04-19', '2024-04-20'],
    'opening_price': [1,  1, None, 0, None, -1, -1],
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')

p = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', width=300, height=300)
circles = p.scatter(x='datetime', y='opening_price', source=df)
hovertool = HoverTool(
    tooltips = [('datetime', "@datetime{%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}")],
    formatters = {"@datetime": "datetime"},
    renderers = [circles]
)
p.add_tools(hovertool)
show(p)


